Synchronising multiple kinects
I'm currently working on a project and I suppose I need help to solve some errors. I've spend a lot of time trying to connect two kinects V2 to one PC. I followed installations instructions of xlz trough this github - https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file -
To help to understand my environment, below our initial set up : 

GPU Nvidia Quadro P6000 
Windows 10
 - Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 installed 
Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 installed  
Cmake 3.28.1 installed
Python 3.8
Anaconda Prompt


For Windows /  Visual Studio installation : somebody already tried it ? how did you managed it ? (Visual Studio Version, Python version...?), it could be really helpful !

For Windows / vcpkg installation
After Libfreenect2 driver being installed succefully with vcpkg, the principal error returned with this commmand -  : « pip install pylibfreenect2 : pip install pylibfreenect2 »
is
"Collecting freenect2
Using cached freenect2-0.2.3.tar.gz (10 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [43 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 353, in 
main()
File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 335, in main
json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 149, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pq7idsgv\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 368, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
self.run_setup()
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pq7idsgv\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 497, in run_setup
super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pq7idsgv\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 313, in run_setup
exec(code, locals())
File "", line 8, in 
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pq7idsgv\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_init_.py", line 108, in setup
return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pq7idsgv\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\core.py", line 146, in setup
_setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pq7idsgv\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 278, in init
Distribution._init(self, dist_attrs)
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pq7idsgv\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\distutils\dist.py", line 286, in _init
self.finalize_options()
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pq7idsgv\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 630, in finalize_options
ep(self)
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pq7idsgv\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 650, in _finalize_setup_keywords
ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pq7idsgv\normal\Lib\site-packages\cffi\setuptools_ext.py", line 216, in cffi_modules
add_cffi_module(dist, cffi_module)
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pq7idsgv\normal\Lib\site-packages\cffi\setuptools_ext.py", line 49, in add_cffi_module
execfile(build_file_name, mod_vars)
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pq7idsgv\normal\Lib\site-packages\cffi\setuptools_ext.py", line 25, in execfile
exec(code, glob, glob)
File "binding/freenect2_build.py", line 11, in 
extra_compile_args = codecs.decode(subprocess.check_output(
File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 489, in run
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in init
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details."


Anyone for help please ?
